# flock() does not seem to work with fork()

Tags: c, linux

This is embarrasing, apparently I don't (again?) understand something basic about forking...

I expected the code (under Linux, Centos 6.3) below to print

```
lock returned 0
unlock
lock returned 0
unlock
```

but it does not, both locks succeed at once:

```
lock returned 0
lock returned 0
unlock
unlock
```

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

void main() {
    int fd = open("lock.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    int lock_ret;

    fork();

    lock_ret = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
    printf("lock returned %d\n", lock_ret);
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(4);

    printf("unlock\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

If I delete `fork()` and just start two processes by hand, then everything works as expected, one lock succeeds, the other blocks and succeeds later.

Comment: It might be working as I understand from your printed output. One of the two forked processes gets the lock... sleeps, unlocks... While this happens, the second process to run has run its flock, and it is waiting for the first process to unlock. This is what you see in the printf()'s, process_1 starts (process_2 starts, but waits), process_1 sleeps and finishes, then process_2 runs and finishes.

Comment: describe what's wrong. what error do you get ?

Comment: @JorgeTorres  no, what you are saying is _not_ what is happening.  The second process _is_not_ waiting.  That is the problem.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Linux [`flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) man page:

> Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file description (see open(2)).  This means that **duplicate file descriptors** (created by, for example, **fork(2)** or dup(2)) **refer to the same lock**, and this lock may be modified or released using any of these descriptors.

The behavior you're seeing is expected.

Comment: sorry...  I don't understand, please help me and explain more.  From your answer, the behaviour should be as I expected - the first printout above.  It is not, it prints the second way.

Comment: First process calls flock and gets the lock. Second process calls flock, kernel sees the lock is already held for that file descriptor, call succeeds immediately. The two processes are working on "the same" file descriptor, it's as if there was only one process calling flock twice for that fd.

Comment: Oh....!  "File descriptor" is not merely a "number", there is whole hidden state machine behind it.  I get it.  How do I synchronize parent and child access to a file then?

Comment: Open after the fork, or use some other synchronization facility (semaphores for example).

Comment: OK, but, the reason that I want to initialize first and then fork, is because of efficiency.  I have lots of children and it is slow to always open after a fork.  Same with semaphores - I checked, I can't `sem_init()` and then `fork()`. Is there a way to initialize a synchronization mechanism once, in the parent and then use it in all the many children?

Comment: `fcntl` advisory locks. But measure performance, no idea if that's any better than an `open` on a hot fd.

Answer (score 2):

According to man flock :

> Locks created by flock() are associated with a file, or, more
>   precisely, an open file table entry. This means that duplicate file
>   descriptors (created by, for example, fork(2) or dup(2)) refer to the
>   same lock, and this lock may be modified or released using any of
>   these descriptors. Furthermore, the lock is released either by an
>   explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these duplicate descriptors, or
>   when all such descriptors have been closed.

So, Because you fork the process after opening the file, they share a same lock. It means that another process cannot flock on the same file, until both child and parent close the file.

Comment: So...?  I am not asking about another process.  I am asking about the child and parent _only_.

Answer (score 2):

If you want exclusive locks not preserved across forks, you can use `fcntl`.

```
struct flock fd_lock = { F_RDLCK, SEEK_SET, 0, 0, 0 };

fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fd_lock);  // not across fork/exec
```

Comment: OK this is great, but... how to I get this thing to block and not fail immediately in either parent or child?

Comment: @MarkGaleck `F_SETLKW` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's some weasel wording in the manual for [`flock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock):

> Locks created by `flock()` are associated with an open file table entry. This means that duplicate file descriptors (created by, for example, `fork(2)` or `dup(2)`) refer to the same lock, and this lock may be modified or released using any of these descriptors.

You can demonstrate this by more thoroughly instrumenting the program, and by adding another fork judiciously.  It's also a good idea to ensure that the file is created properly — when you use `O_CREAT`, `open()` needs a third argument to specify the file mode.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld:%d: Before fork 1\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid());
    fork();
    printf("%ld:%d: After  fork 1\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid());

    int fd = open("lock.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    int lock_ret;

    fork();
    printf("%ld:%d: After  fork 2\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid());

    lock_ret = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
    printf("%ld:%d: lock returned %d\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid(), lock_ret);
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(4);

    lock_ret = flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
    printf("%ld:%d: unlock returned %d\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid(), lock_ret);
    fflush(stdout);
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
        printf("%ld:%d: PID %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", (long)time(0), (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
1451543977:5731: Before fork 1
1451543977:5731: After  fork 1
1451543977:5731: After  fork 2
1451543977:5731: lock returned 0
1451543977:5732: After  fork 1
1451543977:5733: After  fork 2
1451543977:5733: lock returned 0
1451543977:5732: After  fork 2
1451543977:5734: After  fork 2
1451543981:5731: unlock returned 0
1451543981:5733: unlock returned 0
1451543981:5732: lock returned 0
1451543981:5731: PID 5733 died with status 0x0000
1451543985:5732: unlock returned 0
1451543985:5734: lock returned 0
1451543989:5734: unlock returned 0
1451543989:5732: PID 5734 died with status 0x0000
1451543989:5731: PID 5732 died with status 0x0000
```

Note how the processes that do not share the same open file description are blocked; those that do share the same open file description are not blocked.

Also note that time stamping and (especially) 'PID stamping' the output helps make the output unambiguous.